# Linux terminal skipping some (repeating/whitespace) characters

Tags: terminal, ncurses

In some console applications my Linux server has started "stripping" certain repeating characters, affecting the user interface significantly.

Here are a few examples:

[image: htop view with uneven columns and CPU graphs] This htop view has inconsistently sized CPU graphs and inconsistent columns.

[image: iptraf-ng view with uneven columns] [image: iptraf-ng main menu with box characters missing]
These iptraf-ng views show the menu box characters not being "filled out" and the columns in a live view not being even.

A few points:

1. This only happens on PuTTY on Windows and the Cygwin (mintty) shell on Windows, confirmed. I haven't tested if it happens on Mac OS X Terminal. It does NOT happen at the local console.
2. It does not occur if you SSH to the machine from another Linux text console.
3. My high-level suspicion is that this has something to do with terminal types. However, another Linux server I have does not exhibit this behavior on PuTTY or Cygwin. Both of them report `$TERM` as being set to `xterm`.
4. I've tried reinstalling ncurses on the server in question, which should have also refreshed the terminfo files, with no resolution.
5. Both machines - both the one working fine and the one exhibiting this behavior - are using `en_US.UTF-8` as the locale (the `LANG` variable). Both have had `locale.gen` executed recently.
6. Apps exhibiting this behavior all seem to be curses-based apps. Pure terminal apps are fine.

If it is relevant, both systems are Arch Linux 64-bit, with all current patches applied.

Can someone help pinpoint/solve the is

Comment: Have you experimented with setting `TERM` to other valid terminal entries?

Comment: This is caused by a recent change in `terminfo` denoting that TERM=xterm (and variants) support the `REP` (repeat previous character) escape sequence, which several other terminal emulators don't (yet), or just have added support. See e.g. https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=384620 for details.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394834/ for what seems to be another question on this subject.  @egmont, why not post an answer as an answer?

Comment: @JdeBP haha, you're right. Posting it as an answer as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is triggered by a recent change in the `terminfo` database (part of `ncurses`) denoting that `TERM=xterm` (and variants) support the REP (repeat previous character) escape sequence, which several terminal emulators other than `xterm` don't (yet), or just have added / soon will add support.

See e.g. the [Konsole](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=384620) or [gnome-termial](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=787701) bugreports for further details.

Comment: This is definitely the issue. The solution seems to be setting the TERM variable to `xterm-color` at least for now. I'm not sure if/when Windows tools will get updated to support the change...

Comment: `vte` version 0.50.1 has just been released, it adds support for the `REP` escape sequence. I assume Arch Linux will update the package pretty soon.

Comment: The _correct_ solution, fdmillion, is to set the terminal type to `putty-256color`, given that the terminal emulator in the question is PuTTY.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560992/5132