# Ncurses not displaying window border correctly in gnome-terminal

Tags: arch-linux, gnome-terminal, ncurses

I am learning how to use ncurses, and I have noticed that for some reason, in gnome-terminal (on arch) ncurses window borders are not being displayed properly. It seems to work fine in xterm.
[image: Gnome-Terminal]
[image: Xterm]

Not sure what could be causing this, and I haven't had any luck googling. Any ideas?

Comment: See this same question (and my answer) at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394787/linux-terminal-skipping-some-repeating-whitespace-characters/394965.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it, changing $TERM to "gnome" solved the problem. See https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1738655#p1738655

Comment: Forcing `$TERM` doesn't "fix"  your problem; it shifts it one space to the right.

Comment: Can you please suggest a proper solution then?

Comment: Do NOT set `$TERM`.

Comment: I had not set `$TERM` before when it was broken.

Comment: This is actually the right answer jasonwryan.  `TERM` must match the terminal.  If `TERM` had the value `xterm` or `screen.xterm-256color` before, the terminfo description _did not match the actual terminal_.  [`gnome` or `vte` are the proper descriptions for GNOME Terminal](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-vte).

Comment: @JdeBP Nope, `gnome-terminal` has for many years set `TERM=xterm` (and recently `xterm-256color`), and a lot of work has been done to make its emulation behavior as well as the generated escape sequences as close to xterm's as reasonable. `TERM=gnome` and `vte` have been abandoned for many years now, not tested at all by vte/gnome-terminal developers, and due to the tons of recent changes in vte's behavior I'm pretty sure that these obsolete terminal descriptor files actually cause plenty of issues.

Comment: @egmont That does seem like it is the issue. Thanks for the info. Until the problem is solved in gnome-terminal I guess I will either just use xterm or leave TERM=gnome. If you post an answer I will be happy to accept it as you answer is more informative/correct than mine.