# Why my colors doesn't show in all terminals?

Tags: terminal, gnome, colors

I have the following piece of code.

```
bold=''
reset=$(echo -en '\033[0m')
black=$(echo -en '\e[1;30m')
magenta=$(echo -en '\033[00;35m')
blue=$(echo -en '\e[1;34m')
cyan=$(echo -en '\e[1;36m')
green=$(echo -en '\e[1;32m')
orange=$(echo -en '\e[1;33m')
purple=$(echo -en '\e[1;35m')
red=$(echo -en '\e[1;31m')
white=$(echo -en '\e[1;37m')
yellow=$(echo -en '\e[1;33m')
lime_yellow=$(echo -en '\e[1;33m')
power_blue=$(echo -en '\e[1;34m')
blink=$(echo -en '\e[1;31m')
reverse=$(echo -en '\e[1;31m')
underline=$(echo -en '\e[1;31m')

if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 &>/dev/null; then
    echo "tput color is supported."
    tput sgr0 # Reset colors
    bold=$(tput bold)
    reset=$(tput sgr0)
    black=$(tput setaf 0)
    magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
    blue=$(tput setaf 33)
    cyan=$(tput setaf 37)
    green=$(tput setaf 64)
    orange=$(tput setaf 166)
    purple=$(tput setaf 125)
    red=$(tput setaf 124)
    white=$(tput setaf 15)
    yellow=$(tput setaf 136)
    lime_yellow=$(tput setaf 190)
    power_blue=$(tput setaf 153)
    blink=$(tput blink)
    reverse=$(tput smso)
    underline=$(tput smul)
else
    echo "tput color is not supported. Use old school colors."
fi

echo ${red}RED${green}GREEN${yellow}YELLOW${blue}BLUE${purple}PURPLE${cyan}CYAN${white}WHITE${reset}
```

Basically there are two types of colors, `tput` generated or the old-fashioned escape characters like `\e[1;32m`. Since the `tput` type is more interesting, for example, it supports blinking and underline, the code uses `tput` type color if possible. Here is an image to prove it works as expected in Oracle Linux 7.6 (kinda like RedHat or CentOS) GUI environment.

[image]

When I run it from other terminals, it doesn't work. For example, below is the snapshot when running in MobaXterm.

[image]

I also tried `putty` and it doesn't work either. Is there anything wrong with my code?

---

#### Update

I executed `echo $TERM` in each of the terminals and below is the result.

```
Oracle Linux with Desktop environment (color works)
Output: xterm-256color

MobaXterm on Windows (color doesn't work)
Output: xterm

putty on Windows (color doesn't work)
Output: xterm
```

Comment: What matters is the terminal (and maybe some other things), not the kernel or distribution. Can you add to the question, which terminal you are using each time.

Comment: What is the value of `$TERM` in the non-working cases?

Comment: I updated and added related terminal information and the output of `$TERM`.

Comment: The escape sequences are not "old school" compared to `tput`.  This is a misconception.  Indeed, `tput` for many terminal types retrieves similar escape sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These codes should work :

```
    magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
    blue=$(tput setaf 4)
    cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
    green="$(tput setaf 2)"
    purple=$(tput setaf 5)
    red=$(tput setaf 1)
    white=$(tput setaf 7)
    yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
```

Comment: Thank you! I also found this just now. It's the terminal's capability doesn't support the colors besides these 8.

Comment: `gray` color is missing

Answer (score 6):

You must configure your terminal type as [`putty`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty), [`putty-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty-256color), or [`putty-sco`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty-sco) when using PuTTY, or things based upon it such as MobaXTerm.  They are the only terminal types whose entries in the terminfo database *correctly describe PuTTY*.

It is a widespread *incorrect* assumption that terminal emulators are all compatible with XTerm, and that the `xterm` and `xterm-256color` entries in the terminfo database correctly describe them.

This erroneous thinking [is called out in Thomas Dickey's XTerm FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#other_versions-id) and it is worth observing that the `xterm` and `xterm-256color` entries do not even describe all versions of XTerm, let alone other terminal emulators.

The `putty` entry in the terminfo database describes a terminal that is only capable of 8 ECMA-48 colours.  As, indeed, does the `xterm` entry.  But merely switching from `xterm` to `xterm-256colour` *is wrong*.  PuTTY differs from XTerm.

In fact, PuTTY is quite capable of indexed colour (256 colours from a palette) using ISO/IEC 8613 control sequences.  Indeed, since 2017 it is quite capable of *direct* colour (24-bit RGB colour) using ISO/IEC 8613 control sequences.  The `putty-256colour` entry describes the former.  terminfo does not have a way to fully describe the latter.

Use the *correct* terminal type, and `tput` will look up the *correct* control sequences.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419092/5132

Answer (score 0):

It's the terminal's capability that doesn't support the colors besides the 8 basic ones. I found this piece of code to test all available color (source: [tput setaf color table? How to determine color codes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269077/tput-setaf-color-table-how-to-determine-color-codes)):

```
# Connector fifos directory
read TMPDIR < <(mktemp -d /dev/shm/bc_shell_XXXXXXX)

fd=3
# find next free fd
nextFd() { while [ -e /dev/fd/$fd ];do ((fd++)) ;done;printf -v $1 %d $fd;}

tputConnector() {
    mkfifo $TMPDIR/tput
    nextFd TPUTIN
    eval "exec $TPUTIN> >(LANG=C exec stdbuf -o0 tput -S - >$TMPDIR/tput 2>&1)"
    nextFd TPUTOUT
    eval "exec $TPUTOUT<$TMPDIR/tput"
}
myTput() { echo -e "$1\ncr" 1>&$TPUTIN && IFS= read -r -d $'\r' -u $TPUTOUT $2
}
tputConnector

myTput op op
myTput "setaf 7" grey
myTput "setaf 16" black
fore=("$black" "$grey")
for ((i=0; i<256; i++)) ;do
    myTput "setab $i" bgr
    printf "  %s%s  %3d  %s" "$bgr" "${fore[ i>231 && i<244||(i<17)&& (i%8<2)||
        (i>16&&i<232)&&((i-16)%6*11+(i-16)/6%6*14+(i-16)/36*10)<58
        ? 1 : 0 ]}" $i "$op"
    (( ((i<16||i>231) && ((i+1)%8==0)) || ((i>16&&i<232)&& ((i-15)%6==0)) )) &&
        printf "\n" ''
done
```

Below is the output from all three terminal I've tested.

- Oracle Linux with Desktop environment
  [image]
- MobaXterm on Windows
  [image]
- putty on Windows
  [image]

So it's the terminal doesn't support the colors besides the 8 basic ones. To be safe and portable, use just these 8 colors.

Comment: That's great! Would you mind adding a link to where you found that piece of code? It might have other interesting code examples ...

Comment: @AdminBee Added.

Comment: Ok, I see! That site definitely has other interesting code examples ;)